# Using pk argument with Django crispy forms form_action

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Is there anyway to pass an argument in to a model FormView using django crispy forms?

I'm setting the url like:

```
self.helper.form_action = reverse(my_url, args={'pk': self.instance.pk})
```

I even tried overriding `get_form()` by doing:

```
form = super().get_form(form_class)
form.helper.form_action = reverse(my_url, args={'pk': self.kwargs.get('pk')})
```

and neither of those worked I keep getting an error thrown saying there is no reverse match where the `pk` argument is blank.

I realize I could just set this in the template, but I'm using an abstract template which also works for loading the form (and just the form) dynamically into modals so that would require me to restructure all of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
form.helper.form_action = reverse('url_name', args=[self.instance.id])
```

or

```
form.helper.form_action = reverse('url_name', kwargs={'pk': self.instance.id})
```